# Ruby Online payment handle by moneris itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use moneris payment gateway, where I will redirect some info to moneris page and customer will enter Credit card details and do the payment. Finally API should redirect to our application.

Is any one know this one?

Or any other API support this one. We want to use CAD currency here.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [activemerchant](http://activemerchant.org/)
this is the documentation about moneris gateway: http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/ActiveMerchant/Billing/MonerisGateway